# How to add PuTTY private key to OpenSSH client

Tags: ssh, putty, key-authentication

I am trying to setup scp on a new Ubuntu 14.04 system. This system will act as an SSH client to an already configured SSH server on another Ubuntu 14.04 system. I can use putty to SSH into the existing SSH server instance but I am having trouble configuring the new client system with the private key. I am the only user of these systems so I am using the existing private key since it corresponds to the public key already on the SSH server.

On the new client system so far I have added the private key to the `~./ssh/known_hosts` file and the `/etc/ssh/<username>/authorized_keys` file. I have also modified the `sshd_config` to allow RSA based authentication. When I run my scp command on the client I get this output:

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.17.99 (192.168.17.99)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 8a:cc:5b:f0:c4:ef:d7:e1:94:67:59:72:8d:a9:60:0b.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.17.99' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
cp: cannot stat ‘user@192.168.17.109’: No such file or directory
```

I originally created the key pair with puttygen. I uploaded the private key file (.ppk) to the client system and used cat to merge the contents into the `~./ssh/known_hosts` file which I then copied over to `/etc/ssh/user/authorized_keys` file. Both of these files are identical with both the public and private keys included. Here is my ssh config:

```
Host *
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

I think the problem may be with the ECDSA. It looks like something is calling for ECDSA keys but I am using RSA based keys. Is this the problem? If so, what controls this and how do I change it? One more concern of mine is that the contents of the known_hosts and authorized_keys files appear to be in a putty specific format so I an wondering if that may also be a problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the specific commands you used to generate your keys, how you have modified sshd_config and how you added your key.

Comment: did you convert putty ppk to openssh format before merge?

Comment: @rush - not formally no, I did however remove some of the putty specific headers. How would I officially convert?

Comment: @user53029, putty key is multiline with headers. if you removed only headers it makes no sense. to convert you can use `ssh-keygen -i -f /path/to/ppk/pub`

Comment: Getting uudecode failed

Comment: ok was able to use puttgen to convert to openssh format, got the file on the system and replaced the contents of the known_hosts file with the contents of the newly created openssh file but still get the same error

Comment: pub keys are stored in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys not in known_hosts

Comment: Where does the private key go on the client system?

Comment: This has been resolved. Question can be closed.